# Why is ggplot's geom_freqpoly ignoring my binwidth?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(q1,aes(avg, group=class)
       ) + geom_freqpoly(aes(color=class), binwidth = 1.0
       )
```

I would like this to produce several freqpoly lines that are histograms, one per class, where the counts are binned by binwidth 1.0.  Almost working, but I'm getting X axis ticks (and bins I believe) at 1.0, 1.25, 1.333, 1.5, 1667, 1.75, 2.0, etc.  That's not even an even length between ticks.  What gives?

Comment: Yep, that was it. Submit it as an answer, and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oftentimes when you have an unevenly spaced scale like that, it is because the axis variable is discrete (a factor) rather than continuous.  If it is discrete, then the `binwidth` doesn't matter because each discrete value is treated separately.  If `avg` is a factor, you could see this result.